# QsciScintilla on Pyqt4 for python35 error (unofficial whl)

Tags: pyqt4, python-3.5, qscintilla

I want to use pyqt4 on python35. However, the latest official release supports py=<34
So I found this university website [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)
which unofficially extended support for later versions including python35

My problem is that QsciScintilla is not working. I tried to run this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qsci
from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = QsciScintilla()
    editor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The window becomes unresponsive then crashes:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)
```

The reason I want to use pyqt4 on python3.5 is that I have a quit big application built on pyqt4
and I want to upgrade python version of the project to 35

Comment: execute on the CMD/console

Comment: @eyllanesc same result, the window pops up then crashes due to infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Might your problem been solved after reformatting (refactoring, in somehow) the file as the follows:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = QsciScintilla()
    editor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> And also comment me to show the version of your PyCharm as well as the Operating System to solve you more better.

Answer (score -1):

I moved to PyQt5. It is always not a good idea to use an unofficial package.

Comment: That's obviously not a good answer. Provide your PyQt5 code and *try* to explain why it happens as a proper **answer**. (Here's not a *question* but an *answer*) See the StackOverflow guidelines for details.